# Laravel 5 Send Errors to Email

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to figure out how I can send errors to my email in Laravel 5.  I haven't had much luck finding any good resources.

There used to be good packages like:
https://github.com/TheMonkeys/laravel-error-emailer
That did this for you in Laravel 4.

They have yet to release a Laravel5 update because of the way they changed error handling... which I am also not to familiar with.

I have a few Laravel 5 applications which I need to monitor but I need a more efficient way of doing it besides checking error logs on storage.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I know there are others out there seeking this information as well.

Comment: Try out this package for L5 https://github.com/squareboat/sneaker

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can do this by catching all the errors in the `App\Exceptions\Handler::report()`. So in you `App/Exceptions/Handler.php` add a `report` function if its not already there.

```
/**
 * Report or log an exception.
 *
 * This is a great spot to send exceptions to Sentry, Bugsnag, etc.
 *
 * @param  \Exception  $e
 * @return void
 */
public function report(\Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof \Exception) {
        // emails.exception is the template of your email
        // it will have access to the $error that we are passing below
        Mail::send('emails.exception', ['error' => $e->getMessage()], function ($m) {
            $m->to('your email', 'your name')->subject('your email subject');
        });
    }

    return parent::report($e);
}
```

If you need more info, refer to laravel documentation form [mailer](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail) and [errors](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/errors).

Comment: This doesn't work if the listener implements a queue because the closure cannot be serialized

Comment: Very good solution!, btw is there anyway to inject the Request also to print it?

Comment: @AryehArmon the general [php `Exception` class implements `__toString`](http://php.net/manual/en/exception.tostring.php) so you can just return that whole object and it will cast with the trace (at least in PHP 7). `Mail::send('emails.exception', ['error' => $e], function...`

Comment: @Nico `Handler::report` function does not take request as an parameter. Thats how its been implemented. However, if you want any particular data or message in it, you can attach it to the `Exception` and get the message.

Comment: I think that you need to add "use Mail;" to the code if not you are going to receive "Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Mail' not found in"

Comment: Works! Btw. It is also triggered when abort(404) - Page not found... so condition !empty($e->getMessage()) fixes that

Answer (score 7):

The other answers seem quite right. We have done this a while ago and found one big issue with this: If the mail command fails, it can result in a infinite loop of throwing an error and trying to send the according email which will result in a failure again... This will fill up the log quite quickly and kill your server.

**Bear this in mind and don't send an email in that case.**

Side Note: I decided to put this in the answer because it is relevant to all answers and should not get hidden in one comment.

Comment: We can just use 
`try {
  // email errors to someone
} catch {
  // catch any exceptions and do nothing
  // so infinite loop will never happen
}`

Answer (score 6):

EDIT: I found a 3rd party log system built for Laravel

www.understand.io

### Very nice solution, doesn't email me, but this works for what I need.

I played around with this and went through the Laravel core files and came up with something similar to what you see on an error page.

You just need to create a view file that echos out $content for the email

```
public function report(\Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof \Exception) {

        $debugSetting = Config::get('app.debug');

        Config::set('app.debug', true);
        if (ExceptionHandler::isHttpException($e)) {
            $content = ExceptionHandler::toIlluminateResponse(ExceptionHandler::renderHttpException($e), $e);
        } else {
            $content = ExceptionHandler::toIlluminateResponse(ExceptionHandler::convertExceptionToResponse($e), $e);
        }

        Config::set('app.debug', $debugSetting);

        $data['content'] = (!isset($content->original)) ? $e->getMessage() : $content->original;

        Mail::queue('errors.emails.error', $data, function ($m) {
            $m->to('email@email.com', 'Server Message')->subject('Error');
        });
    }

    return parent::report($e);
}
```

Comment: Your answer is exactly like what I have suggested, except for you have added bunch of code that is specific to your need which you have not mentioned in the question.

Comment: Bro if it means that much to you I give you the answer

Comment: The point I am trying to make is that your answer is too specific to your problem. But my suggested answer will help many others the way it helped to resolve your issue. The good question or answer should be the one that helps as many people, not just 1.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Exception Handler](http://laravel.com/docs/master/errors#the-exception-handler) for this. Place your mail code in the report function and it will email you the error every time one occurs.

Answer (score 2):

I expanded on West55's answer, to include some request info in the email.  Useful to know, especially when you want to try and duplicate the error yourself.  It's wrapped in a try/catch just to make sure we don't throw another exception while getting request info.

```
 public function report(Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof Exception){

        $debugSetting = \Config::get('app.debug');
        // email err if debug off (in prod env)
        if (!$debugSetting){
            \Config::set('app.debug', true);
            if (ExceptionHandler::isHttpException($e)) {
                $content = ExceptionHandler::toIlluminateResponse(ExceptionHandler::renderHttpException($e), $e);
            } else {
                $content = ExceptionHandler::toIlluminateResponse(ExceptionHandler::convertExceptionToResponse($e), $e);
            }
            \Config::set('app.debug', $debugSetting);

            $lc2 = (isset($content->original)) ? $content->original : $e->getMessage();

            // add request info to err msg
            $lc1= '';
            try{
                $request= request();
                $lc1=
                    "<div>" .
                    "-- Request --<br>" .
                    "<br>Method: " . $request->getMethod() .
                    "<br>Uri: " . $request->getUri() .
                    "<br>Ip: " . $request->getClientIp() .
                    "<br>Referer: " . $request->server('HTTP_REFERER') .
                    "<br>Is secure: " . $request->isSecure() .
                    "<br>Is ajax: " . $request->ajax() .
                    "<br>User agent: " . $request->server('HTTP_USER_AGENT') .
                    "<br>Content:<br>" . nl2br(htmlentities($request->getContent())) .
                    "</div>";
            }catch (Exception $e2){}

            if (strpos($lc2, '</body>') !== false){
                $lc2= str_replace('</body>', $lc1 . '</body>', $lc2);
            }else{
                $lc2.= $lc1;
            }
            $la2['content']= $lc2;      //put into array for blade

            $ln1= Mail::send('emails.exception2', $la2, function($m){
                    $m->to('support@mydomain.com')
                    ->subject('Fatal Error');
            });
        }
    }
    parent::report($e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for Laravel 5.3

```
#file:   /app/Exceptions/Handler.php

public function report(Exception $e)
{
    if($this->shouldReport($e)){

        \Mail::send(
            ['html' => 'error.emails.exception'],
            ['content' => $data['content']],
            function ($m) {
                $m->from(['myemail@from.com']);
                $m->to(['myemail@to.com']);
                $m->subject('Crash Report');
            }
        );
    }

    parent::report($e);
}
```

- You need to create the exception.blade.php file in /resources/views/emails
- I advise you to use [this content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33290853/2615737), to make the email look the same as Laravel's error page.

Comment: Very good solution!, btw is there anyway to inject the Request also to print it?

Comment: @Nico I don't understand what you want. Do want to add _what_ to _where_ ?

Comment: yeah, just noticed that i asked almost nothing. In the email that is going to be sent, is good to know also what request the user made, like the headers, post params and get params. Is there a way to inject those and print them all?

Comment: From where the `$data`variable come from ?

Comment: @Mistre83 Check my second note. It links to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33163893/laravel-5-send-errors-to-email/33290853#33290853

Comment: You can use request() helper method

Answer (score 1):

Theres a package here https://github.com/designmynight/laravel-log-mailer that adds a mail driver to Laravel 5.6's LogManager which should do exactly what you are after.

There are configuration settings in the config/logging.php file and you can create different mail channels for logging information to different recipients. The email template is also customisable.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a solution for Laravel 6.x with an html error description, trace, and all vars if somebody wants to increase, there should be a render also for the mysql queries that can be added to this html body.

**Important! dont forget to put your Debug config in false**, you can do that in the env file setting:

```
APP_DEBUG=false
```

Or you also can changing it in the /config/app.php file

```
 /*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Debug Mode
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When your application is in debug mode, detailed error messages with
| stack traces will be shown on every error that occurs within your
| application. If disabled, a simple generic error page is shown.
|
*/

//'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),
//to
'debug' => false, //now not lookin for the envfile value
```

Otherway all the users are going to see a DEBUG SCREEN with a lot of private information.

The solution is to extend the Handler in
/app/Exceptions/Handler.php

and replace the function Render for the next code.

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    $html = $this->renderExceptionWithSymfony($exception, true);

    $array = $this->convertExceptionToArray($exception);

    $html .= $this->renderVars($_SERVER, "Server Vars");
    $html .= $this->renderVars($_REQUEST, "Requests Vars");
    $html .= $this->renderVars($_COOKIE, "Cookies");
    
    \Mail::send('emails.error', ['html'=>$html], function ($m) {
        $m->to('developer@mail.com', 'Server Message')->subject('WEB ERROR');
    });
    
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

And also add the new function renderVars next to the new render. This functions is going to convert the Sever, request an cookies arrays to a legible

```
public function renderVars($vars, $titulo)
{
    $html = '<table class="trace-details">
                <thead class="trace-head">
                    <tr>
                        <th><h3 class="trace-class"><span class="exception_title">'.$titulo.'</span></h3></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>';
            forEach($vars as $key=>$value)
            {
                $html .= '<tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <span class="block trace-file-path">
                                            <span title="'.$key.'"><strong>'.$key.'</strong></span>
                                        </span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span class="block trace-file-path">';
                                        if(!is_array($value))
                                        {
                                            $html .= '<span title="'.$value.'"><strong>'.$value.'</strong></span>';
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            $html .= '<span title="ARR | '.implode(', ', $value).'">ARR | <strong>'.implode(', ', $value).'</strong></span>';
                                        }
                                        $html .= '</span>
                                    </td>';
                                $html .= '</tr>';
            }
                    $html .= '</tbody>
                                </table>';
    return $html;
}
```

And for the last thing you need to create a blade view in the folder /resources/views/emails/error.blade.php this blade is in this case only printing the html error formatted from render function. The mail function send array param and convert for the view.

In this case the code for the blade error template (/resources/views/emails/error.blade.php) is only:

```
<?=$html?>
```

That print the formated html received.

Next to that if you want to customize the error frontend screen you need to create a new blade template in the folder (/resources/views/errors/<error_code>.blade.php) like:
500.blade.php ----> for Internal Server Errors
404.blade.php ----> for not found errors.
If you wan't to do that, laravel is going to show the default error template.

I hope that is helpfull for other people.

best regards,
Reb duvid.

Answer (score 0):

**/config/logging.php**

```php
// ...
        'monitoring-mail' => [
            'driver' => 'custom',
            'via' => App\Logging\Mail::class,
            'level' => env('LOG_MONITORING_MAIL_LEVEL', 'error'),
            'to' => env('LOG_MONITORING_TO'),
            'from' => env('LOG_MONITORING_FROM'),
        ],
// ...
```

**/app/Logging/Mail.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Logging;

use App\Helpers\Log\MailHandler;
use Monolog\Logger;

class Mail
{
    public function __invoke(array $config)
    {
        $handler = new MailHandler($config['to'], $config['level'], $config['bubble'] ?? true, $config);
        return new Logger('mail', [$handler]);
    }
}
```

**/app/Helpers/Log/MailHandler.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Helpers\Log;

use Illuminate\Mail\Message;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler;
use Monolog\Logger;

class MailHandler extends AbstractProcessingHandler
{
    /** @var string */
    protected $to;

    /** @var array */
    protected $config;

    public function __construct(string $to, $level = Logger::DEBUG, bool $bubble = true, ?array $config = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($level, $bubble);
        if (empty($to)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('"To" cannot be empty');
        }
        $this->to = $to;
        $this->config = (array) $config;
    }

    protected function write(array $record): void
    {
        $body = $record['formatted'] ?? $record['message'] ?? '<empty>';
        Mail::raw($body, function (Message $message) use ($record) {
            $subject = ($record['level_name'] ?? 'ERROR') . ': ' . ($record['message'] ?? '<empty>');
            $message->to($this->to);
            $message->subject($subject);
            if (!empty($this->config['from'])) {
                $message->from($this->config['from']);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Nov 14, 2020, accepted answer no longer the best answer, so I will set new one:

1- Go to file `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`, modify `register()` like this:

```
public function register(): void
{
    $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {
        $this->sendEmail($e); // <<< add this line
    });
}
```

2- In same class `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` add this function:

```
public function sendEmail(Throwable $exception): void
{
    try {
        // prepare data
        $content = [];
        $content['message'] = $exception->getMessage();
        $content['file'] = $exception->getFile();
        $content['line'] = $exception->getLine();
        $content['trace'] = $exception->getTrace();
        $content['url'] = request()->url();
        $content['body'] = request()->all();
        $content['ip'] = request()->ip();
        $content['app_locale'] = App()->getLocale();
        // end prepare data

        // >>>> here handle sending email or SMS ...

    } catch (Throwable $exception) {

        Log::error($exception);

    }
}
```